# Paste Format to Object Inside Group

Tags: microsoft-visio-2010

In Visio 2010, how do you paste formats to objects inside a group?  Attempting to paste formats to an object inside a group applies them to all objects in the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the group and click **Format > Behavior**

[image]

In the **Behavior** form in the *Behavior* tab, in the **Group behavior** section pay attention to the value of **Selection**. By default Visio sets this to **Group First**

[image]

But there are three values you can choose from that determine how Visio will behave when you click on a shape.

[image]

Select **Members first**

Now when you use the Format Paint command when you click on a shape in that group, the formatting will be applied just to the shape you clicked on, instead of the entire group.